# TwinColSelect sorted the Rightcolumn according to Leftcolumn - How can i stop the sorting

Tags: java, vaadin7

When i select an item from LeftColumn of TwinColSelect field then RightColumn field is sorted automatically according to Leftcolumn field. Is it possible to stop sorting according to Leftcolumn? If possible how can i do that?
my code is:

```
final protected TwinColSelect select;
select = new TwinColSelect("selectCategories", categories);
        select.addValueChangeListener((event) -> {
            checkButtonState(nextButton);
        });
        select.setItemCaptionPropertyId("name");
        select.setLeftColumnCaption("LeftColumn");
        select.setRightColumnCaption("RightColumn");
```

Here, **categories** is the data source.